# React Native (iOS) - index.js EPERM error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

after upgrading to XCode 14.3 (to comply with Apple's requirement about iOS SDK 16), I get a "[native] index.js: EPERM: operation not permitted, uv_cwd" error when starting my React Native app.

The React Native libraries are at least a year old, but I don't think those would be necessarily triggering this error (and until 3 months ago they compiled just fine)

I looked up this error but I found mostly answers for the "regular" NodeJS environment, not React Native's.

Thanks!